# Why does Visual Studio 2010/12 take a lot of memory and time to run a program in debug mode?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have a project which reads in a text file (approx 2.6  GB in size), aggregates the data at some level and writes out a smaller file.

I've observed that if I run the program from Visual Studio in debug mode, it takes a lot of time to run (about 45 mins).

Instead, if I open a command prompt, move to the Debug folder in my Visual studio Projects folder and run the same exe, it completes in almost 10-15 mins.

I've also observed that the memory consumption is very high when running through Visual Studio.

I'm not stepping through the code, nor do I have any breakpoints in it. Why does Visual studio take so much longer to run the same executable compared to running it directly from cmd?

**P.S.**

- I tried searching for this type of issue here, but most questions are about Visual Studio taking long while stepping through, or taking too long to start execution in debug mode.
- I couldn't find anything about why the same executable takes much, much longer while running through Visual studio when everything else is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major cause of a probgram running much slower inside Visual Studio than outside is because of the [Debug Heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which does a lot of error checking.

Try setting the environment variable `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP` to 1 in the project's settings (Debugger -> Environment) to disable this (see [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366705%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

This should make it run a lot faster, though obviously you're not going to get as much error-checking - *caveat emptor*.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it, when running inside the debugger, it (VS and debugger) will load the debugging environment, "instrument" and "analyze" the execution and will let you stop, set breakpoints, check and modify values, ...

When just running the DEBUG version, you will not load up all the debugger environment, you will just run the exe.

now, when you will compile your project in RELEASE, them will will be even faster.